# How to disable single file from being cached

Tags: .htaccess

I have a file called xxx.php and in htaccess i have

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

how can i disable xxx.php file being cached?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead to exclude `xxx.php`:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!xxx\.php$).*\.(js|css|html|php)$">
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```